# null value and countDistinct with spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very simple dataframe

```
  df = spark.createDataFrame([(None,1,3),(2,1,3),(2,1,3)], ['a','b','c'])

  +----+---+---+
  |   a|  b|  c|
  +----+---+---+
  |null|  1|  3|
  |   2|  1|  3|
  |   2|  1|  3|
  +----+---+---+
```

When I apply a `countDistinct` on this dataframe, I find different results depending on the method:

#### First method

```
  df.distinct().count()
```

> 2

It's the result I except, the 2 last rows are identical but the first one is distinct (because of the null value) from the 2 others

#### Second Method

```
  import pyspark.sql.functions as F
  df.agg(F.countDistinct("a","b","c")).show()
```

> 1

It seems that the way `F.countDistinct` deals with the `null` value is not intuitive for me.

Does it looks a bug or normal for you ? And if it is normal, how I can write something that output exactly the result of the first approach but in the same spirit than the second Method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`countDistinct` works the same way as [Hive `count(DISTINCT expr[, expr])`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF):

> count(DISTINCT expr[, expr]) - Returns the number of rows for which the supplied expression(s) are unique and non-NULL.

The first row is not included. This is common for SQL functions.

Comment: so how to count the NULL as a distinct value then?

Comment: @xiaodai `df.select('a').distinct().count()` will include NULL rows in the count, but is not the most performant when running over multiple columns