# how can I get the number of each column's non-empty value / empty value?

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark

I have over 100 columns in a dataframe called ele_df,
and I'd like to get the number of non-empty values for each column and let the numbers displayed in a table with corresponding column names.

But when I tried this code below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, isnan, lit, sum

def count_not_null(c, nan_as_null=False):
    pred = col(c).isNotNull() & (~isnan(c) if nan_as_null else lit(True))
    return sum(pred.cast("integer")).alias(c)

ele_df.agg(*[count_not_null(c) for c in ele_df.columns]).show()
```

it returns to me:

|74876506|          74876506|        74876506|      74876506|            74876506|            74876506|       74876506|  74876506|            74876506|                 74876506|         74876506|           74876506|  74876506|          74876506|   74876506|                    74876506|    74876506|     74876506|74876506|  74876506|   74876506| 74876506|    74876506|  74876506|    74876506|  74876506|      74876506|   74876506|    74876506|               74876506|   74876506|          74876506|
which means every cell has a value but the truth is there are so many empty cells like this:

```
    +-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |Business_ID_2|Elementum_Attribute_5|Elementum_Attribute_6|
    +-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |             |                     |                     |
    |             |                     |                     |
    |             |                     |                     |
    |             |                     |                     |
    |             |                     |                     |
    |             |                     |                     |
    |             |                     |                     |
```

And when i use distinctCount() for these columns, it all returns one, I guess it considers the empty value as an actual value?

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`distinctCount` does not count nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345117/null-value-and-countdistinct-with-spark-dataframe), which suggests to me the empty rows in your data is not null, but likely empty strings, e.g. `''`.

You can try adding a check for size or whether it equals to empty string. Something like

```
pred = (
  (col(c).isNotNull())
  & (~isnan(c) if nan_as_null else lit(True))
  & (col(c) != '')
)
```