# Spark SQL distinct strange behaviour on multiple columns with one of them has null values

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Why the below first query gives a different result? Shouldn't it be 28685985? The runtime is Databricks 14.1 (Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12)

Table `consensus_normalized` (ParameterId string, Period string, CalendarPeriod string, RevisionDate timestamp), and only `CalendarPeriod` has `null` values.

```py
df1 = spark.sql("select count(distinct ParameterId, Period, CalendarPeriod, RevisionDate) from xxx.v3_2.consensus_normalized")
df1.show()

df2 = spark.sql("select count(distinct ParameterId, Period, RevisionDate) from xxx.v3_2.consensus_normalized")
df2.show()

df3 = spark.sql("""SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    ParameterId, 
    Period, 
    CalendarPeriod, 
    RevisionDate
  FROM xxx.v3_2.consensus_normalized
)""")
df3.show()
```

[image]

Comment: _"and only CalendarPeriod has `null` values."_ - SQL gives `NULL`s special handling in so many areas, including `SELECT DISTINCT` _and_ `COUNT()` (and of course, in `SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ... )`). See the manual: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-null-semantics.html

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40345377/2412701